# Android createNewFile returns false

Tags: android, file

I want to create a new file in Android:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "filename");
if (file.exists())
  file.delete();
file.createNewFile();
```

But the file.createNewFile() always returns false. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: use `try{file.createNewFile();}catch(IOException e){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `"filename"` is a non-empty directory, `file.delete()` won't erase the directory for you, hence this logical problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you were to use `Context.openFileInput(filename)`, it would handle file creation for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the Android [File doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29):

> Creates a new, empty file on the file system according to the path
>   information stored in this file. This method returns true if it
>   creates a file, false if the file already existed. Note that it
>   returns false even if the file is not a file (because it's a
>   directory, say).

You need to call the  [FileOutputStream Context.openFileOutput(String,int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method.

```
FileOutputStream out=openFileOutput("file.txt",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```